# Using units on CSS perspective

Tags: css, perspective, css-transforms

Just a quick question to clear up some confusion that I have regarding units on CSS `perspective`.

On the CSS Transforms spec it references it with `px` e.g. `perspective: 1000px;` but I have used and in many other places others have used it without `px` e.g. `perspective: 1000;` such as on W3Schools.

Is either way more preferred? Does it matter?

Just want to clear this up, thanks.

Comment: never trust W3Schools - http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Haha, yea I was thinking theirs might be old - but browsers as far as I'm aware accept unprefixed syntax and even a few posts on here didn't use units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because it's accepted by (some) browsers doesn't mean it's correct.
Specifying a unit of measurement is [required by the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths), unless the value is zero.

The spec says:

> Lengths refer to distance measurements and are denoted by <length> in the property definitions. A length is a dimension. A zero length may be represented instead as the <number> ‘0’. (In other words, for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional.)
>
> A dimension is a number **immediately followed by a unit identifier.**

(emphasis mine)

See the [Distance Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) and the [Other Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#other-units) for examples.

Also see the MDN discussion of [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length)

Answer (score 0):

px (or other absolute unit) is the correct way. Here is documentation (better than w3 schools) :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/perspective