# Perspective property (css3) not working on Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, browser, mozilla

I have created an HTML file in that I want to do animation with CSS3 animation to open/close door. Using Perspective property to do this task.

My code is successfully working in Google Chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox browser.

My code is-

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>demo perspective</title>

<style>
#box{
    margin:100px;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background:#343454;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: door 2s linear 0s infinite;

    -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
    -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -moz-animation: door 2s linear 0s infinite;

    transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
    transform-origin:0% 0%;
    animation: door 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes door{
    0%{
        -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(80deg);
        -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
    50%{
        -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
    100%{
        -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
        -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes door{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(80deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    }
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="box"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the unit of your perspective [`px`,`em`,`pt`,etc].

In your code, it should be:

```
transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(20deg);
```

Instead of:

```
transform: perspective(300) rotateY(20deg);
```

The number without a unit is meaningless and [invalid according to the w3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#dimensions), unless the value is `0`. (You can also refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997177/using-units-on-css-perspective)

On another note, you should also have a non-prefixed `@keyframes`, as most [newer browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).